# Android browser width stretched to iframe content width, despite overflow:hidden

Tags: android, iframe, mobile, scroll, stretch

I'm trying to mimick desktop-style iframes in Android (Dolphin browser) with some succes. The trick used is to put an `<iframe>` with `position:relative;` inside a `<div>` with fixed dimensions and `overflow:hidden;`, then using jQuery Mobile (or rather just the vmouse events) to handle mouse events for scrolling.

All this works fine except for one thing; Even though the `<iframe>` is clipped, it's content stretches the browser to match size. This is mostly noticable in height.

Here's simplified example code in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/euKhG/

And here's the result to watch within the Android browser: http://jsfiddle.net/euKhG/embedded/result/ (only works in Android browser!).

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? I've seen iScroll and similar suggested elsewhere, but they seem to touch frames with a remote `src` like this.

Answer (score 2):

try setting target-densitydpi in meta tag

```
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160dpi"/>
```

but you'll have to change all other css with respect to this as well

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, I think you missed something here. Right now your iFrame is getting cut off yes, but not due to you setting overflow:scroll, nor due to you setting a width/height property of the container frame; the cutoff that you are currently seeing is entirely arbitrary.

To prove this, add a background:#ff0000 to your container div, and you will see that it truly is not the div's width / height that is defining the cutoff region of your iframe but rather some 'default' iframe dimension properties: http://jsfiddle.net/kauUr/

My recommendation is, given you said your div is of fixed dimensions, set up your iframe with width/height properties of those same dimensions so that it matches. You can either do this using the width and height attributes, or more cleanly using css justas you have done for the container div. Once you give the iFrame the correct width / height, the cutoff should match what you expect and the browser shouldn't scroll to the size of the contents of the iframe, but rather to your specified dimensions. In fact, even if the div's dimensions aren't known ahead of time, you can use Javascript to acquire them and then correctly size the iFrame in runtime.

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow: scroll; background:#ff0000">
    <iframe style="width: 400px; height: 400px" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>​
```

And if that doesn't work, try slapping an `overflow:none` in the iframe style as well.

Comment: This only makes it look worse in Android.